# 2000s (or earlier) animated fantasy film: girl marries prince, dies in an accident but comes back as a spirit to watch over her baby every night

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I'm looking for the title of an animated movie where the girl marries the prince. They have a baby but she gets into an accident shortly thereafter. I don't think she dies immediately but her spirit visits her baby every night to sing it to sleep, I think...

I don't remember if I saw this in DVD or CD but I think I watched it in the Philippines before 2006. But I don't think it's a Filipino animation, though.

Comment: It reminds me of an European tale ["Brother and Sister"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brother_and_Sister). Do you remember, if the accident is caused on purpose by someone else? Or if there is an animal (for example a deer), the princess' spirit visits too?